# Multiple column in order by clause - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have two columns in a table say, LIKE and FAVORITES (int value)

See the chart:

```
╔════╦══════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ LIKE ║ FAVORITE ║
╠════╬══════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║   25 ║        9 ║
║  2 ║    5 ║       17 ║
║  3 ║    6 ║        1 ║
║  4 ║   45 ║        0 ║
║  5 ║    3 ║       44 ║
╚════╩══════╩══════════╝
```

Now, I want to select the Maximum Like and Favorites IDs from the SELECT clause.
I have tried

```
SELECT ID from TABLE WHERE CONDITION ORDER BY LIKE,FAVORITES DESC
```

But the result shows the rows based on LIKE DESC order.

The result should be

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  5 ║
║  4 ║
║  1 ║
║  2 ║
║  3 ║
╚════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add those two columns. eg,

```
SELECT ID
FROM tableName
ORDER BY `LIKE` + FAVORITE DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4620b/2)

Result:

```
╔════╗
║ ID ║
╠════╣
║  5 ║
║  4 ║
║  1 ║
║  2 ║
║  3 ║
╚════╝
```