# While joining two tables in mysql i am getting error as "Unknown column 'm.machinenumber' in 'on clause' "?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

[image][image]while joining two tables,i executed one query but it is not displaying second table data properly instead it is showing garbage value..

The query i used is,

```
select p.machinenumber,
max(case when (p.shift)=1 then xxxx end) s1_xxxx,
max(case when (p.shift)=2 then xxxx end) s2_xxxx,
avg(case when (p.shift)=1 then yyyy end) s1_yyyy ,
avg(case when (p.shift)=2 then yyyy end) s2_yyyy 
from pdata p
inner  join (select  count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=1  then ename end) s1_wa,
count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=2 then errorname end) s1_we,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=1 then errorname end) s2_wa,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=2 then ename end) s2_we,
count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s1_merror,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s2_merror  from mstop)m
on p.mnumber=m.mnumber
where date(p.proddate)='2013-02-25';
```

Please solve this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have not *projected* the column `mnumber` on the subquery. You need to `SELECT` the column name inside the subquery in order to be visible on the joins. Don't forget to add `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

```
select  p.machinenumber,
        max(case when (p.shift)=1 then xxxx end) s1_xxxx,
        max(case when (p.shift)=2 then xxxx end) s2_xxxx,
        avg(case when (p.shift)=1 then yyyy end) s1_yyyy ,
        avg(case when (p.shift)=2 then yyyy end) s2_yyyy 
from    pdata p
        inner  join 
        (
            select  mnumber,
                    count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=1  then ename end) s1_wa,
                    count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=2 then errorname end) s1_we,
                    count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=1 then errorname end) s2_wa,
                    count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=2 then ename end) s2_we,
                    count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s1_merror,
                    count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s2_merror  
            from    mstop
            GROUP   BY mnumber
        ) m on p.mnumber=m.mnumber
where   date(p.proddate)='2013-02-25'
GROUP   BY  p.machinenumber
```

Comment: man i beat you this time...sorry but you answered before me everytime when i tried to wrote answer so i delete my answer afterward but now i beat you.

Comment: @DipeshParmar I have no problem with  that (*not a big deal for me*) but I was wondering why everytime I answer a question you eventually delete your answer? I'm not telling you delete it. I'm not competing against any other users here. Let me ask you, are you sure that the query gives you the correct results even if you have added `mnumber` on the subquery? `:D`

Comment: nope never..i never delete any answer or never down-vote anyone without extreme condition...you can see down-vote ratio is so much lower in my profile..

Comment: Thank u.. I am not getting error now, first 5 columns are executing properly but remaining 6 are not getting displayed..

Comment: give us some records that we can played with so we can help you work it out `:D`

Comment: see this question, it has sample records with desired result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15131682/multiple-column-in-order-by-clause-mysql

Comment: I added two tables which are used in that query.. so please check it once

Comment: how about changing `from    pdata p
        inner  join` into `from    pdata p
        LEFT  join`? have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried all the joins, then too its displaying only first columns and remaining 6 columns are not getting displayed..

Comment: yes I tried all the joins, then too its displaying only first 5 columns and remaining 6 columns are not getting displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to also return `mnumber` for `m.mnumber`. Inside inner join of mstop table you need to also return `mnumber` in order to join it according to `mnumber`.

```
inner  join (select  count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=1  then ename end) s1_wa,
count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=2 then errorname end) s1_we,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=1 then errorname end) s2_wa,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=2 then ename end) s2_we,
count(case when (shift)=1 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s1_merror,
count(case when (shift)=2 and (ename)=0 then ename end) s2_merror,
     mnumber  from mstop)m
on p.mnumber=m.mnumber
```

Comment: Thank u.. I am not getting error now, first 5 columns are executing properly but remaining 6 are not getting displayed..

Answer (score 0):

If the garbage is coming from the second table, try `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`